# MongoDb c# Linq query and return a collection's child objects

Tags: linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

Say I have a typical customers and orders scenario. I have a collection of customers and each customer document has a list of orders. Now I want to query the customers where the order date is within the last week, i.e. is greater than DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7) and less than DateTime.UtcNow.

```
var startDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);
var endDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
var query = collection.AsQueryable<Customer>()
    .Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderDate > startDate && o.OrderDate < endDate))
    .SelectMany(b => b.Orders);
```

This results in the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The SelectMany query operator is not supported.
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.SelectQuery.TranslateMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression) in C:\\build\\mongo-csharp-driver\\Driver\\Linq\\Translators\\SelectQuery.cs:line 687
```

My current solution is pretty nasty:

```
var customers =
    collection.AsQueryable<Customer>()
        .Where(c => 
            c.Orders.Any(o => 
                o.OrderDate > startDate && 
                o.OrderDate < endDate))
        .ToList();

var results = new List<Order>();
foreach (var orders in customer.Select(c => 
    c.Orders.Where(o => 
        o.OrderDate > startDate && 
        o.OrderDate < endDate)))
{
    results.AddRange(orders);
}

return results;
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an almost general rule, I wouldn't embed orders in customers. It seems a very natural query to find all customers *without* fetching all the orders they have ever made. Also, orders usually have a pretty complex lifecycle and represent long-running business transactions so they are worth a separate document.

Of course, this depends a bit on your exact requirements, but customer is so central that you could argue to also embed payments, inquiries, cancellations, invoices, and basically any other business transaction that is related to a customer in some way, so you end up stuffing all data in a single unmanageable collection.

In any case, it's easier to query `db.Orders.find({"OrderDate" : {$gt : lastWeek} });` and then use the `$in` operator to find the customers through `Order.CustomerId`.

If the number of orders in the last week is large (say > 10,000), it makes sense to introduce a `MostRecentOrder` field in the customer or use map/reduce instead. It's also possible to paginate the orders and then use the `$in` operator on the resulting chunks of smaller size. If you do that, make sure to sort by some stable criterion like the `OrderDate`.